# Render using GLSurfaceView.Renderer without any layout

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have been struggling to implement a way to rendering opengl.

I have a GLSurfaceView.Renderer class and I want to use it inside an Android Service to generate images.

I want it to render images on a scheduled basis, like in every second. But it doesn't trigger onDrawFrame method whatever I try.

So far, I tried many things;

- Calling requestRender
- Inflating layout then calling layout.draw(canvas)
- Using GLWallpaperService https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService

Comment: That's just a utility class.  Are you trying to draw to an offscreen buffer?

Comment: Im saving rendered frame as bitmap. It works fine when I run it by attaching to a view.

Comment: But without a view attached to renderer. No matter how much I try, I can not trigger rendering

Comment: `GLSurfaceView` and `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` are helper classes that really ought to be in a support library.  You don't need to use them to use GLES.  Just set up the EGL context and surface yourself.  See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for some examples.